# Send large amount of data from PHP to RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm implementing RabbitMQ to listen requests from a PHP application (Sender) to be responsible for sending emails through a receiving script (Receiver).
PHP (aka Sender) sends the email data to RabbitMQ, and another PHP script (aka Receiver) takes the content, assembles the email and sends it. Without creating "lag" in the Sender application that has to wait for the sending of the email to be completed.

Initially I considered sending a JSON containing the main items I need, such as the email and sender name, recipient email, subject and email content.

However, analyzing the current code, I saw that there is a need to send attachments such as CID images and large HTML content to the recipient.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

I'm still considering using JSON and encoding the CID images and attachments as Base64, all this being sent by the Sender, and then decoded by the Receiver. But I don't know if there's anything very good.

Comment: The consumer needs to produce and send the email. The sender should send as less as possible. You could store the data in a database and just send the ID.

Comment: @MarkusZeller It's a good idea. Maybe something like MongoDB to not affect my production database could be a solution.

Comment: Why not. You could have just an extra database server for that purpose.

Comment: +1 for staging the data outside of RMQ. It's been some years, but I recall running into some not-fun problems trying to stuff GBs of image data back and forth through Rabbit. Depending on your volume, throughput, and performance requirements you might want to use something like Redis that holds the data in memory to avoid bouncing it off of a disk in the middle.